# Show $\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)=\sum_{1\leq d\leq x}\sum_{1\leq m\leq x/d}f(d)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

I have been trying to get my head around this step in a proof, but havn't been able to,

**Question**: Show $$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)=\sum_{1\leq d\leq x}\sum_{1\leq m\leq x/d}f(d)$$

**Attempt**:

I know we have to remove $n$ and replace it with $m$, so first let $n=md$

Then substituting in $m$ to remove $n$ we get, $$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)=\sum_{1\leq md\leq x}\sum_{d\mid md}f(d)$$

Also I know that $d\mid md \Leftrightarrow \exists e\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $de=md$

I am not really sure how to continue from here, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, as you showed

\begin{align}
\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\left(\sum_{d|n}f(d)\right)&=\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\left(\sum_{n=md}f(d)\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{1\leq md\leq x}f(d)\\
&=\sum_{1\leq d\leq x}\left(\sum_{1\leq m\leq x/d}f(d)\right).
\end{align}
For $(1)$, as you note, $d|n$ is equivalent to $n=md$, but it is not convenient to write as you tried to do, also, you wrote a condition which is ever true: $d|md$. For the las line, we want to sum over the $d$'s, so, if we want also that $md\leq x$ (in order to be equivalent to the last sum) we need $m\leq x/d$.

Answer (score 1):

In the first summation, you are summing up the values of $f$ over all divisors of all numbers between $1$ and $x$.

In the second summation, you are looking at it from a different point of view. You consider all numbers $d$ between $1$ and $x$, and look at how many times $d$ occurs as a divisor of an integer between $1$ and $x$: clearly this number is the integer part of $x/d$.